# like button comment show not appearing

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-like

I want make comment box work on my page after like. I don't know what i do wrong.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=282750891760090";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<?php
<fb:like href=\"myurl"\" send=\"false\" layout=\"button_count\" width=\"90\" show_faces=\"false\"></fb:like>
?>
```

og:tags

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Foczky" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Foczky" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100000432662947" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much of a php expert, but wrapping your fb:like html inside of  tags doesn't seem like it would work too well.  Also, your HTML is missing  and  tags too.